# How to stored wordpress user data in sales force account

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

1 I have registered form in my site, I need to stored my user data in my salesforce account.

2 Any way to stored user data in salesforce account without using salesforce form.

3 We have installed plugin in my site.

4 Any hook using this i can stored user data in salesforce ?

5 Would you please help for that, It will appreciate for us.

Comment: create a custom plugin

Comment: which plugin have you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Use Gravity Forms on WordPress and Try Zapier to Integrate Gravity Forms Data with Salesforce.

You need premium version for integrating with Salesforce.